# Storing time series data in Azure SQL

Tags: database, azure-sql-database

I am collecting data(1 data per second) for 60 minutes in mobile application. These 3600 data points will be processed and sent to Azure SQL. Currently, I store 120 data points in a single row. However, it still took me around 10-20 seconds. Quit the application in the halfway will cause some of the data failed to save to SQL. Is there any method to accelerate the process of storing data to SQL or queue the SQL writing process so I would not miss any data?  I am developing the mobile application using Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can send that data to Azure Event Hub and load them into Azure SQL Database using Azure Functions. To take the data from Event Hub to Azure SQL Database please read [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169531/Sending-events-from-Azure-Event-Hub-to-Azure-SQL-D). To save data to Event Hub please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide).